# Mapping data to ground truth list

Tags: pandas

I have ground truth data in the following Python list:

```
ground_truth = [(A,16), (B,18), (C,36), (A,59), (C,77)]
```

So any value from:

```
0-16 gets mapped to A, 
17-18 maps to B, 
19-36 maps to C,
37-59 maps to A 
60-77 maps to C
and so on
```

I am trying to map a time series input say from numbers like

```
[9,15,29,32,49,56, 69]  to its respective classes like:
[A, A, C, C, A, A,  C]
```

Assuming my input is a Pandas series like:

```
in = pd.Series([9,15,29,32,49,56, 69])
```

How do I get to the series `[A, A, C, C, A, A,  C]` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's my approach:

```
gt = pd.DataFrame(ground_truth)

# bins for cut
bins = [0] + list(gt[1])

# categories
cats = pd.cut(pd.Series([9,15,29,32,49,56, 69]), bins=bins, labels=False)

# labels
gt.loc[cats, 0]
```

gives

```
0    A
0    A
2    C
2    C
3    A
3    A
4    C
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Or, without creating new dataframe:

```
labels = np.array([x for x,_ in ground_truth])
bins = [0] + [y for _,y in ground_truth]        

cats = pd.cut(pd.Series([9,15,29,32,49,56, 69]), bins=bins, labels=False)

labels[cats]
```

which gives:

```
array(['A', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'C'], dtype='<U1')
```